# Can I create local version of .gitignore that applies only to my local repository?

Tags: gitignore

There are some files/directories in the remote git repository for my project that I don't want in my local repository. They are useful to other project members, but not me. And I can't just identify them in the root .gitignore file because when that file becomes part of the remote repository it becomes the rule for everybody else so they change it back. We don't want to get into a .gitignore war. 
Is there a straightforward way for me alone to selectively chose the files/directories that I do or don't want to exchange between the remote repository and my local repository when I do a 'git pull'? To be clear, I'd like to make my selections once and have them take effect every time I do a 'git pull' (or equivalent) and not force them on anyone else.

Comment: Yes, there’a a file `.git/info/exclude` which can act as a private version of `.gitignore`.

Comment: `.gitignore` does not apply to files that are already tracked.

Comment: I don't think `.git/info/exclude` excludes files coming _FROM_ origin/upstream

Comment: My understanding, like that of Andreas, is that .git/info/exclude only applies to files/directories going in the other direction. That is, with it you can identify local files that you don't want included in the remote repository. Not the other way, which is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You can add .gitignore to your .gitignore file.
You then git rm .gitignore and it is no longer tracked.
Then just remove the other files you don't want tracked.

Comment: That seems like a workable solution, although it runs slightly counter to the spirit of git as maintaining a shared work space. Having said that, you could argue my request is a similar violation of a slightly lesser degree.